# The Fashion of Food: IACP's Annual Conference 2012 (NYC)

Tags: discussion, conferences, site-promotion

The [International Association of Culinary Professionals](http://www.iacp.com/) is holding their [annual conference](http://www.iacp.com/attend/category/2012_annual_conference) at the end of March / beginning of April. This year, it's being held in New York City. I'll be running a booth representing Seasoned Advice in their [Culinary Expo](http://www.iacp.com/attend/more/2012_culinary_expo).

I'm doing this build awareness among culinary professionals about this site, and hopefully encourage some professional chefs, cookbook authors, and food bloggers to give the site a try, as well as to just build some brand awareness in the food community more generally.

So! Consider this your (not-so-)formal invitation to swing by and say hello if you're in NYC on April 1. Alternatively, if you are not attending but know people who are, help spread the word and tell them to come by the Seasoned Advice table for free swag.

**Sunday, April 1
12:30 - 4:30 p.m.**

**82 Mercer St., New York, NY**

(Tickets are required for this event and may be purchased from the IACP's website.)